# Android UITableView lib not scrollable?

Tags: java, android, uitableview, listview

I am using [this lib](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview/blob/master/android-uitableview/src/br/com/dina/ui/widget/UITableView.java) to achieve the iOS look of my ListView. My problem is that it does not seem to be scrollable. I can't wrap the UITableView with a ScrollView because then the nasty scrollbar totally destroys my layout.

My xml for the ListView looks like this:

```
<br.com.dina.ui.widget.UITableView 
    android:id="@+id/options_listView" 
    style="@style/UITableView"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay a ScrollView with a LinearLayout in it and in the LL the ListView helped me out. `android:scrollbars="none"` fixed the layout destruction and everything is fine :)